# Angular 2: ngFor loop undefined value

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

I have a simple `*ngFor` loop and I cannot figure out why it's throwing an error

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let comment of [{'employee': 'jeremy lopez', 'desc': 'blah blah blah'}]">
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <div class="initial-container">
        <div class="flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <div>{{ comment.employee }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-avatar>
    <p>{{ commment.desc }}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

this throws an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'desc' of undefined` even though it's clearly defined.  When I move the `{{ comment.desc }}` up a couple lines in the DOM, it works:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let comment of [{'employee': 'jeremy lopez', blah: 'blah blah blah'}]">
  <ion-avatar item-left>
    <div class="initial-container">
      <div class="flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div>{{ comment.employee | initialFormat }}</div>
        <p>{{ commment.desc }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-avatar>
</ion-item>
```

which is great and all, but I need to be able to access `comment.desc` outside the `<div class="initial-container"></div>`.

**Can someone explain what's happening?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`commment` is `undefined`, but `comment` is defined. You have a typo.

Comment: -_- sheeeeeeshh